# Как задать в Jquery атрибут name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как правильно назвать имя в Jquery, если в html прописан атрибут name из php массива? Просто DATA[name] js не понимает, и скрипт не срабатывает

```
$postData = array(
    'TITLE' => $leadData['TITLE'],
    'NAME' => $leadData['NAME'],
    'PHONE_WORK' => $leadData['PHONE_WORK'],
    'EMAIL_WORK' => $leadData['EMAIL_WORK'],
);
<input type="text" name="DATA[NAME]" placeholder="Ваше имя">
if (document.form.DATA[NAME].value == '' || document.form.phone.value == '' ) {
        valid = false;
        return valid;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php код кажется нужно в специальных тегах писать `<?php ?>`

те должно быть что-то вроде

```
<?php
$postData = array(
    'TITLE' => $leadData['TITLE'],
    'NAME' => $leadData['NAME'],
    'PHONE_WORK' => $leadData['PHONE_WORK'],
    'EMAIL_WORK' => $leadData['EMAIL_WORK'],
);
?>
<input type="text" name="<?php echo $postData['NAME'] ?>" placeholder="Ваше имя">
if (document.form.<?php echo $postData['NAME'] ?>.value == '' || document.form.phone.value == '' ) {
        valid = false;
        return valid;
    }
```